# Best estimate of random variables through known linear combination of them

Tags: statistics

I am somehow struggling in how to get the best estimate of a set of random variables when the observed value is a known linear combination of them.

My data is:

[image]

I would like to get the contribution of each of the variables x1, x2, x3 to Y.

In the example, 1*x1 + 0*x2 + 2*x3 = 47,678 and so on...

If I had a univariate set of datapoints, it would just be the slope of the tendency line.

Can anyone give a hand on this?
Thanks

Comment: What does "best" mean, here?  And what is the point of the variable $x_2$ since it never appears?

Comment: Note:  a standard notion of "best" would be to minimize least square error. That is, minimize $\sum_i(a_ix+b_iy-c_i)^2$ but of course you might have something else in mind.

Comment: "Best" means the value of x1, x2, x3 that minimizes the square error of the estimation of Y. In this case x2 is not contributing to the estimation.

Comment: So, then, each of your "equations" has the form $a_ix+b_iy-c_i=0$ and you want to minimize $F(x,y)=\sum_i(a_ix+b_iy-c_i)^2$.  This is a fairly standard linear fit.  Just take the gradient of $F$ and solve for $\nabla F=(0,0)$.  That just means solving two linear equations simultaneously.   You have the coefficients in a file somewhere, presumably, so this should be an easy computation.

Answer (score 0):

Sketch:

$x_2$ has no significance here, so I'll leave it off.  In what follows, $x=x_1, y=x_3$.

You have a number of expressions of the form $$a_ix+b_iy-c_i$$ and you seek to minimize the function $$F(x,y)=\sum_i (a_ix+b_iy-c_i)^2$$

We compute $$\nabla F=2\left(\sum_i (a_i^2x+a_ib_iy-a_ic_i),\; \sum_i (b_i^2y+a_ib_ix-b_ic_i)\right)$$

Setting $\nabla F=(0,0)$ you get two linear equations that you need to solve simultaneously.

Defining the constants $$A=\sum a_i^2\quad B=\sum b_i^2\quad C=\sum a_ib_i\quad D=\sum a_ic_i\quad E=\sum b_ic_i$$

We get $$Ax+Cy=D\quad \&\quad Cx+By=E$$

Comment: Exactly what I needed!